# Clone a datarow into same table but primary key creatin error

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I'd like to allow the user to clone a record.  Data is from MS SQL db and is contained in a single table with a primary key (int32) autoincrementing titled "CriteriaID".   I get a CriteraID can't be null error which I would expect since it's an ID column.  I tried setting it to allowdbnull in on the dataset side but no luck. How do I set it to the value needed to eventually save it into DB?  If I hit new record that column is -1,-2,-3, etc. but in this case I want to clone all columns EXCEPT for the CriteriaID.  I also tried NOTHING, VBNULL, and a random integer not already in DB.  WOuld it be easier to use a different method?

[image]

```
        Try
        If Not IsNothing(TCriteriaBindingSource.DataSource) Then

            Dim sr As DataRow() = DsCriteria.Tables("tCriteria").Select("CriteriaID = " & DsCriteria.Tables("tCriteria").Rows(TCriteriaBindingNavigator.BindingSource.Position).Item("CriteriaID"))

            sr(0).Item("CriteriaID") = DBNull.Value

            DsCriteria.Tables("tCriteria").NewRow()
            DsCriteria.Tables("tCriteria").Rows.Add(sr(0))

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Set `AllowDBNull` back to `false`. When you pass the param array to `.Rows.Add()`, set the value of the `CriteriaID` Column  to `null` (`Nothing`) (i.e., pass the values from `sr(1)` to `sr(n)`, while the first value passed to `Rows.Add()` is `Nothing`). Remove this: `DsCriteria.Tables("tCriteria").NewRow()`

Comment: Maybe it's more clear written like this: `dim clonedData = sr.ItemArray clonedData(0) = nothing DsCriteria.Tables("tCriteria").Rows.Add(clonedData)`

Comment: I kicks an exception: Column 'CriteriaID' does not allow nulls.                  Dim clonedData = sr(0).ItemArray
                clonedData(0) = Nothing
                DsCriteria.Tables("tCriteria").Rows.Add(clonedData)

Comment: That works if you set `AllowDBNull = false` and `AutoIncrement = true`. Otherwise, you have to provide a new index yourself. -- It looked like what you actually wanted to do.

Comment: YES!  Autoincrement was the problem.  Thank You!

Comment: Please don't leave resolved questions unanswered. It's a great way to waste the time of people who want to help you. For some reason, Jimi refuses to post answers because he apparently doesn't care about using this site the way it was intended to be used so it's up to you to do what he won't and post an answer, so that the rest of us can see that you don't need further help without opening the question and reading the whole thing. It's frustrating to waste time like that so maybe you could show the respect to others that Jimi refuses to.